# A problem on Heat and Evaporation (Solved)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I am stuck on a problem which I don't understand.

The text says:

> "$100$ grams of water are put into a pot. Calculate the necessary heat such that the water completely evaporate, considering the initial temperature to be $38$ Celsius Degrees. (Water heat of evaporation: $\lambda = 22.6\cdot 10^5$ J/kg).
>
> Calculate instead the amount of remaining water if we supply a total amount of energy equal to $2\cdot 10^5$ Joules."

**Attempts**

So, for the first part I met no problem, indeed I solved it quite easily with the heat equation

$$Q = mC\Delta T + \lambda m$$

Hence $\Delta T = 62$ and it's ok (and of course $C = 4186$ J/(Kg K)).

But now when I have to calculate the remaining amount of water in the pot, I got something nonsense.
Using the inverse formula

$$m = \frac{Q}{C\Delta T}$$

I get a nonsense result, which is $m = 0.77$ kg.

But here is the strange thing: the book says the result is $23$ grams, and this is exactly the missing amount from $0.77$ if only that result were been in grams.

Where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should calculate the amount of energy required for rising the temperature of the water from $38$ up to $100$ Celsius Degrees. If this is less than $2\times 10^5J$, then the difference in the energies will cause some water to evaporate by the formula $Q=\lambda m$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't consider the heat difference. How dumb :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The second question is a new situation.

In the second situation you're told to add a specific amount of heat and see how much evaporates, so you need to solve for m using the Q given for the second question. (You also forgot the second term $m \lambda $ when you "inversed" it)